# Getting multiple row values out of MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a total noob at PHP but I'm trying, with the information I can find, to build a script that reads multiple rows from a MySQL table. Each row only contains a number. Let me give an example:

Every ID in the table has a row called "number".

```
ID| NUMBER
1 | 8
2 | 12
3 | 6
4 | 9
```

Now I need a script that - for example - takes ID 1, 2, and 4 and calculates the total amount `8 + 12 + 9 = 29`. 3 is not interesting and I don't want that row in the calculation process. Next this total number needs to be output to a blank website page, so it only shows the total number without anything else.

Examples would be more than welcome and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out sql [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregate function and [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) comparison operator:

```
SELECT SUM(`number`) FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,4);
```

***UPDv1:***

```
<?php
// hostname, username, password and database should be replaced with actual values.
$dbms = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database');

if($dbms->connect_errno)die('MySQL connection error: ' . $dbms->connect_error);

// table should be replaced with actual table name.
$result = $dbms->query('SELECT SUM(`number`) as `amount` FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,4)');

if($dbms->errno)die('MySQL error: ' . $dbms->error);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['amount'];
?>
```

Also, check [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/mysqli) driver for PHP is [*installed*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `SUM()` in your SQL.  This generic sql should work:

```
SELECT SUM(column name) FROM table WHERE condition
```